# Export variable in Mocha test

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

To shed some light on what i'm trying to do is: after the test below is ran I get the `report.json` generated and the token I generated in the before hook and send the report to another api for it to process.

I have a mocha test in which I generate a token and I need this token generate to be shared with another js file.

```
var token = 'un_assigned';

describe('Comparison', function () {
  token = 'sin asignar';
  before(function (done) {
    getToken('app', function (response) {
      token = response.token;
      done();
    })
  });

  files.forEach(function (file) {
    it('Comparing ' + file, function (done) {
      const id = file.split('./screenshots/')[1];
      compare(file, id, token, function (response) {
        expect(response.TestPassed).to.be.true;
        done();
      });
    });
  });

  after(function (done) {
    done();

  })
});


exports.tokenApi = function getToken(){
  console.log(token);
  return token;
};
```

After the test is ran I need to pass the generate token to another JS file so I can process the mocha report. I tried using exports but when I call my function it calls my test. I'm a JS noob is there something im missing ?.

Comment: is something stopping you from generating another token?

Comment: Yes because with that token the results of the are saved into DB and i use that token later to get the results

Comment: Have you tried writing it to a file? Mocha runs on node so you can just import the `fs`module and write the token to a file in a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use the File System (recommended)

Use the `fs` module to write the token to a file, then just read this token as required.

```
const fs = require('fs')
    exports.tokenApi = function getToken(){
      console.log(token);
     // write token to file here
      fs.writeFile('token.txt', token, (err) => console.error(err))
      return token;
    };
```

### Or Use the node module syntax

You were close except you are not exporting your module correctly, you must use the [node module syntax](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports)

```
tokenApi = function getToken(){
  console.log(token);
  return token;
};
module.exports=tokenApi
```

However the second method won't work with your example as the token will only be set after the test has run.

Also you shouldn't import a test suite unless you intend on running tests as a standard javascript file will not have any knowledge of mocha commands.